# Some DLLs referenced by sub-project not being copied to Solution's output folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, build

I have a number of projects which make up a solution. Some of these sub-projects contain 3rd party DLLs which must find their way into the solution's output folder. All the referenced DLLs have the  `LocalCopy` attribute set to `true` and most DLLs are actually copied to the output.

However I am having difficulties getting 3 DLLs from 2 separate projects copied to the output. I have tried the trick of setting `LocalCopy` to `false` and then to `true` but without success. I have tried deleting and restoring the references - also without success.

What else can I do? What is causing this?

Comment: What else can I do? Use a postbuild event, maybe?  copy "$(ProjectDir)Externals\*.dll" "$(TargetDir)" if 'Externals' is the directory containing your DLLs.

Comment: @DavidBrabant - sure, just strange that 90% of the DLLs are copied without needing postbuild event action. Would like to understand what's going on :-)

Comment: Have you tried to check Project Dependencies and Project Build Order? Just right click on solution and check them. Futhmore how about you remove the .sln file and let Visual Studio create you a new one.

Comment: For unmanaged dlls, the only reliable way is a post-build step. That's my experience.

Comment: @devhedgehog - yes, I've done that. As I mentioned, most DLLs are being copied from the projects. Just 3 were not.

Comment: @PMF - I've now added a postbuild action and it now works

Comment: Do you get any errors when running your project since those 3 might be missing?

Comment: @devhedgehog - no, because the DLLs are also in the GAC. I only noticed it after I had packaged the solution and installed on another workstation

Comment: Ahhh this changes everything. The DLLs are in GAC... Leme try something out :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can Add the DLLs manually to your project folder, if they are not being compiled all together.
And check the dependencies in the Project  / Solution Properties.